# Is it possible to see changes that have been made by a user on blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, transactions, blockchain, ethereumjs

Is it possible to see every changes that have been made to the block chain from various accounts.In other words is it possible to see what changes have been done by a user to, say its location(a field in smart contract)?

Comment: I think you need to read more about blockchain. What you describe is just... the exact purpose of this tech.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the changes that are made to the blockchain from an ethereum address. A user can have as many addresses as they want.

**If you know all their Ethereum addresses** (and that's a big, bold if), then yes, it is possible to monitor them and see what they're up to.

Given that there is this concept of [hierarchically deterministic wallets (HD wallets)](https://medium.com/bitcraft/hd-wallets-explained-from-high-level-to-nuts-and-bolts-9a41545f5b0) and that [it's quite trivial to have one with ETH](https://github.com/meth/eth-hd-wallet), **you can be 99.99% certain that you won't be able to track a user if he doesn't want you to**.